# Custom label for Travis CI badge on github repo

Tags: travis-ci, badge

I'm trying to add 2 badges to my github repo readme, so I can see build status of my dev branch and master branch. I was able to add the badges (and they work too) but I'm not able to differentiate between the badge for master or dev.

[image]

Is there a way to add custom text something [dev|passing] [master|failing], etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [shields.io](https://shields.io) which provides quite a lot of badges.

They have one for travis and you can specify the left side text of the badge.

As an example for one of my repo:

The normal link:

Build branch : https://img.shields.io/travis/73VW/TechnicalReport/build.svg

Master branch: https://img.shields.io/travis/73VW/TechnicalReport.svg

Renders as:

[image: Travis]
[image: Travis branch]

A bit of custom:

https://img.shields.io/travis/73VW/TechnicalReport/build.svg?label=Whatever+You+Want
https://img.shields.io/travis/73VW/TechnicalReport.svg?label=Master

Renders as:

[image: Travis]
[image: Travis]

This works this way: https://img.shields.io/travis/USER/REPO/BRANCH.svg?label=YOURLABEL

Be aware that the branch part is not needed if you want to use master branch.

I Agree this slows down a bit the load of your github (or whatever) page because shields.io is not really fast but this is cool.

And you can also change badge style:

- [image: Travis branch]: https://img.shields.io/travis/73VW/TechnicalReport.svg?style=plastic&label=Custom+Label
- [image: Travis branch] : https://img.shields.io/travis/73VW/TechnicalReport.svg?style=flat-square&label=Custom+Label
- [image: Travis branch] : https://img.shields.io/travis/73VW/TechnicalReport.svg?style=for-the-badge&label=Custom+Label
- [image: Travis branch] : https://img.shields.io/travis/73VW/TechnicalReport.svg?style=social&label=Custom+Label

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this isn't possible at the time. I was looking into this a while ago and stumbled upon [this issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5037), which is still open and unresolved.

Comment: Not possible directly but you can use a third party as I mentionned in my comment.